# Texture being dragged has no Sprites. Unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Using standard 2d mode in Unity. After I drop an already imported asset to the scene I get message:

Texture being dragged has no Sprites.

`UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()`

Asset has  Texture Type set to `Sprite`.

Tried different image formats(png, jpg), also restarting unity and re importing images.
Using `Mac Os 10.9`

Comment: It seems like the problem happens when Format is set to Compressed. Any other option works fine

Comment: I had this problem because I first had the textures set to scale to POT (non Power of 2 option under advanced), then I replaced the files with POT versions but the POT setting remained the same. When I changed it to "None" it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

After set the texture type to sprite we have to make it a sprite using Sprite Editor.

for that click Sprite Editor. Select that sprite and set the pivot of that sprite as custom. click apply.

after doing this i was able to drop a asset in to the scene.(even if the format is Set to Compressed).